# Reactjs prop won't populate field when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a connected React component which takes the query string values and makes an API call. Then after mapping state to props, it populates an input field with one of the props. It works fine when I land on the page following the link containing the query strings, but then if I refresh the page the input field doesn't get populated, but the data in the state tree is still there and so are the props.

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ReturnForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  _handleSubmit = () => {
    ...
  };

  loadParcel = () => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const { parcel, instance } = this.props.location.query

    Api.Get(ActionTypes.GET_PARCEL_MANAGEMENT_DETAILS, {parcel, instance}).dispatch(dispatch)
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if(Object.keys(this.props.location.query).length !== 0) {
      this.loadParcel()
    }
  }

  renderReference() {

    const { parcelManagementDetails } = this.props;
    let customerRef

    if(parcelManagementDetails.parcelDetails) {
      customerRef = parcelManagementDetails.parcelDetails.customerReference
    }

    return (
      <div className="input-group">
        <input type="text" defaultValue={customerRef}>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {

    const { quantity } = this.state;

    return(
      <div className="form new-return-form">

        <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
            ...

            <div className="input-section-inner">
                {this.renderReference()}
            </div>

            <div className="button-group">
              <button
                id="addReturnButton"
                type="submit"
                model="local"
                className="btn btn-primary">
                Save
              </button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

  static mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const details =  state.parcelManagementDetails.parcelManagementDetails || {}
    return {
      parcelManagementDetails: details
    }
  }

}


const ConnectedReturnForm = connect(ReturnForm.mapStateToProps)(ReturnForm);
export default ConnectedReturnForm;
export {ReturnForm}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean when you refresh the page then api call return data and that data(`customerReference`) is available as props but not populated in input field?

Comment: @PrakashSharma Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: It looks like `defaultValue` on input field is only set when initialised and doesn't get updated later. I would suggest you to use `controlled` input field.

Comment: Thank you, any link or example please? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37198826/7232300