# Re-render Child component and change child state states when parent state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component which has a state containing an array of object:

```
function ParentComponent(props) {
    const [objects, setObjects] = React.useState([...props.objects]);

    const handleObjectRefresh = () => {
        /**
         * Refresh objects
         */
        setObjects([
            ...newObjects
        ])
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleObjectRefresh} >Refresh</Button>
            {objects.map((obj, index) => {
                return(
                    <ChildComponent obj={obj} />
                )            
            })
        }
        </div>
    )
}

function ChildComponent(props){
    const [objParam1, setObjectParam1] = React.useState(props.obj.param1);
    const [objParam2, setObjectParam2] = React.useState(props.obj.param2);

    useEffect(()=> {
        setObjectParam1(props.obj.param1);
        setObjectParam2(props.obj.param2);
    }, [props.obj])

    return (
        <div>
            <Texfield defaultValue={objectParam1}/>
            <Texfield defaultValue={objectParam2}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My issue is right now the current default values of `Textfield` does not get updated if an object is removed, the object does change in the child component however, the textfield default value are the previous state, I was wondering how can I completely change the child state when the object list in the parent component changes?

**EDIT**

To fix the issue, I simply changed `defaultValue` to `value`

Comment: Try changing the dependency array to `[ props.obj.param1, props.obj.param2 ]`.

Comment: I think this question has the answer you desire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727837/react-change-input-defaultvalue-by-passing-props