# What is the difference betwen value and defaultValue in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am looking at the docs of the react.js and found that input tag with a value cannot be interactive, has to be dealt with the help of state. But there is something called uncontrolled input which need to be dealt with the state. So defaultValue should be used in the uncontrolled input and we can get the value by ref?

```
<input type="text" value="hello" /> 
<input type="text" defaultValue="Hello"/>
```

Please clear my inference on when to use the **defaultValue specifically**. What is the use case for it

Comment: According to https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#default-value `defaultValue` is only used for initial rendering. Interactions by user will have to go through the usual controlled components

Comment: Then what is the point of having defaultValue, as value does the same thing when one has to use controlled components!

Comment: use `onChange={this.handleChange}` and then in `handleChange(event)` you can access the current value of the input box by `event.target.value`. You would use the state to keep track of your value, so you can access it any time. if initially your state will be set it would work as a `defaultValue`

Comment: value pretty much does the same thing @knowbody

Comment: yeah, as @mfirry mentioned `defaultValue` is used only for the initial render

Comment: here is the answer for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146105/react-input-defaultvalue-doesnt-update-with-state