# React uncontrolled component - updating the input fields despite presence of defaultValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an "uncontrolled" React component with an input field like so:

```
render: function(){

return (

      <input
        id="pickupField"
        tabIndex="1"
        placeholder=""
        className="order-form-input"
        onFocus={this.disableAddresses}
        onBlur={() => {
            this.enableAddresses();
            this.fieldChange('address');
        }}
        defaultValue={(order.pickup || {}).address || ''}
        ref="pickupAddress"
        hintText={(this.state.hideHintText) ? "" : "Enter the pickup address"}
        floatingLabelFixed={true}
        floatingLabelText="Pickup Address"
      />
   )
}
```

the problem I am having is that I want to update this component with new data after it's rendered the first time, and using defaultValue instead of value means that the input field text *won't* update after the first render. E.g., the only way to update the text in the input field is for the user to type into it, I cannot seem to change it programmatically.

I can solve this problem by using value instead of defaultValue. However, the reason I do *not* want to use use value instead of defaultValue, is because then I have to use an onChange listener which is way overkill for my use case here.

The reason using an onChange listener is overkill is because I sync with the database everytime the component state changes. I would rather sync on `onblur` instead of syncing on `onchange`.

I see some solutions to this problem out there, using React fields such as "key", but TMK this solution will force the component to re-mount which sounds bad for performance and keeping the logic simple.

**Anyone know how to solve this problem? How to update a React component's input fields programmatically, but avoiding an onchange listener?**

Comment: If you want to go with an uncontrolled component then I believe you have to get a reference to the DOM element of the `input` and update the `value` directly.

Comment: It's not idiomatic react, but gets the job done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717743/2613786