# Update state with useEffect from another page using React hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update state with data from another page. After trying to update state I'm getting error:

> index.js:1375 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

How to properly update state using hooks ??

```
const [data, changeData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    cv: '',
    documents: '',
    rodo: false,
    regulations: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.data) {
      changeData((prevState) => {
        return { data: { name: location.data.name } };
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

Input

```
<div className='form-control'>
                <label htmlFor='name'>
                  <i className='fas fa-user'></i>
                </label>
                <input
                  value={data.name}
                  id='name'
                  name='name'
                  onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChangeData(e, 'name')}
                  type='text'
                  placeholder='Imię i nazwisko'
                />
              </div>
```

Comment: There is no input in the code shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro

Comment: You should use `useReducer` instead `useState` for complex objects [offical docs](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side-effect of coming from Class based component. What you were trying to do in your code is replace entire previous state stored in data with new object that looked like below:

```
{ data: { name: location.data.name } }
```

In Hooks world you define individual item to have individual `useState` but to continue on what you are working on here's the fix:

```
const [data, changeData] = useState({
  name: '',
  email: '',
  phone: '',
  cv: '',
  documents: '',
  rodo: false,
  regulations: false,
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (location.data) {
    changeData({
      ...data,
      name: location.data.name
    });
  }
}, []);
```

Ideally you should be defining individual items in the state something like below:

```
const [name, changeName] = useState('');
const [email, changeEmail] = useState('');
....
const [rodo, changeRodo] = useState(false);
```

And then in your useEffect hook you will change individual item like below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.data) {
    changeName(location.data.name);
  }
}, []);
```

This way, `name` is always defined, and thus the `<input />`s `value` was always set, or *controlled*. [Read on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro)

Comment: Cautiion: This will only run in "componentDidMount" lifecycle. because of`}, []);`

Comment: And how to pass all data?? not only location.data.name but all data.location? How to update all state ??

Comment: While you are right, this does not answer the question.

Comment: @JonasWilms the issue is OP is resetting the data and in `useEffect` which is causing prior known properties to null and thus React raises the issue.

Comment: Yes, and exactly that piece of information was missing. I added that.

Comment: @Freestyle09 you would just use individual setter for each piece if you refactored.