# How to set value of Material UI slider without user input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a slider which will have its displayed value periodically updated.
An example of this would be a playback timeline on Spotify/Soundcloud/YouTube.
I still want the slider to accept user input, which is why I'm not using a LinearProgress component.

However, whenever the value attribute is updated, I receive the following error message:

```
Material-UI: A component is changing an uncontrolled Slider to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled Slider element for the lifetime of the component.
```

Is it possible to control the slider's value without user input? Or do I need to use a LinearProgress and a Slider separately?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47012342/4103661

Answer (score 1):

I have found my mistake.
My initial state's `sliderPosition` was set to null. I fixed it by setting initial state's `sliderPosition` to zero.

This is the post that explains it further:
[A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled error in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro)