# Uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled In Fomik Feild

Tags: formik

Hi i'm using Formik and Yub library to validate Forms .I'm stuck in *uncontrolled input of text to be controlled*

In the beginning i have problem that Initial Values and i fixed with *enableReinitialize={true}* in Formik .But now with Field. On the document says Field can automatically inject onChnange and need props for input  [here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field)

So I did like this

```
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';

<Formik
            initialValues={intialData}
            validationSchema={validationRules}
            onSubmit={e=>console.log(e)}
          >
            {({ errors, setFieldValue, setFieldTouched, values, handleChange }) => (
         <Form>
         <Field name="name" value={data.name} /> //i have tried explicitly added type="text"   
          {error.name ? errors.name: ''}
        </From>
           )}
      </Formik>
```

I didn't use  onChange because Field automatically inject  .But by giving  like this

```
  <Field name="name" value={data.name} />
```

i can't edit on field shows uncontrolled error so I tried like this

```
  <Field name="name" defaultValue={data.name} /> // without giving onchange this also cant edit 

so I tried like this 

<Field name="name" defaultValue={data.name||""}/> // its working but the warning about uncontrolled input not going away
```

How get rid uncontrolled issue in Formik field .Im i doing in right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Initial value is my issue  i fixed  with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro)