# Please tell me why this expression doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({login:'', password: ''});

const changeHandler  = (e) =>{
    setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}

return(
    <div className='login-wrapper'>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => submitHandler(e)}>

            <Input color='primary'
                   margin='dense'
                   placeholder='login'
                   type='text'
                   style={{margin:'20px', width:'300px'}}
                   name='login'
                   value={state.login}
                   onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e)}/>
       </form>
  </div>)}
```

Error:

> A component is changing a controlled input of type password to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: Problem is fromm this part of code     setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro

Comment: What is `Input`? Does it expect the same props as a normal `input`?

Comment: If `Input` does not pass the `name` to the underlying `input` element, `e.target.name` will be undefined. That may not be the issues, but its a possibility.

Comment: yes, it is input I've used material-ui, that's why it is in capital letter

Comment: in console I see the result of e.target.name and e.target.value separately․ But in this expression it doesn't work setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs on `useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

> Unlike this.setState in a class, updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.

If you use an object as the value of a `useState` hook, an update to it must replace **all** values.

What is happening is you are updating `login`, but not replacing `password`. So the password input is presumably the one throwing the warning. The password was set to a string, then it becomes `undefined`.

The solution is simple, spread the previous state values into the new object before updating it:

```js
setState({...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
```

The most optimal change handler would also take advantage of the functional form of the updater and look something like this:

```js
// Destructure the event for cleaner syntax and avoiding the pitfall of pooled events
const changeHandler  = ({ target: {name, value} }) => {
  // Use a functional update to ensure we always have the most recent copy of state
  setState(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of `state.login` becoming undefined, it just fails to update at all.

Comment: Nothing ever said `state.login` became undefined. It just says *a* component. This will solve the problem.

Comment: @LukeStorry There's also a change you tested it before my last update, I had the target destructuring syntax backwards.

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.name` is probably coming through as undefined, so `value={state.login}` as a prop returns `undefined`, which switches the component to non-controlled.

Fix with this:

`const loginChangeHandler = (e) => setState({...state, login: e.target.value});`