# Edit in React get the variable but

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im doing a Edit in React, when i click the button i get the name on the input but im getting this error:

Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Function:

```
editAluno(aluno) {
    this.aluno = aluno.nome
    this.setState({ aluno: aluno.nome })
}
```

HTML:

```
                    <button type="button" onClick={() => this.editAluno(aluno)}>[EDIT]</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled error in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro)

Comment: I tried but I still couldn't :/

Comment: Please try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. This example should probably include an input element that is (or isn't) being controlled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens if `aluno.nome` is **undefined or null,**:

```
<input value={this.state.aluno.nome} ... />
// ☝️ <input value={undefined} will show that warning in this case
```

Try:

```
<input value={this.state.aluno.nome || ''} ... />
                                    ^^^^^^
```

Or, alternatively, do it in the `setState` call:

```
editAluno(aluno) {
  this.aluno = aluno.nome;
  this.setState({ aluno: aluno.nome || '' });
}
```