# Uncontrolled Input to Controlled Input Warning in React Hook Form and Material UI's TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

i'm trying to build a form using React Hook Form (version 7.6.6). I created a FormInput component as seen below:

```
const FormInput = ({ name, label }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

   return (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field }) => {
          return <TextField {...field} label={label} fullWidth required />;
        }}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
```

and i'm using it here:

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
            <FormInput name="firstName" label="First Name" />
            <FormInput name="lastName" label="Last Name" />
            <FormInput name="address1" label="Address 1" />
            <FormInput name="email" label="Email" />
            <FormInput name="zip" label="ZIP code" />
       
         
          <Button
            type="submit"
            Continue to Payment
          </Button>
        </form>
</FormProvider>
```

However, i'm getting an error saying

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled...

I've already checked with React Hook Form documentation and cannot seem to find what's causing the warning. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 38):

I think your problem is similar to this one.

[A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled error in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro)

It is not a problem related to the hook.
In my view, if an input does have no **value** attribute or when **value** is given as undefined in the first place, it is considered as uncontrolled input.
So I want to suggest 2 solutions.

**1) Setting defaultValue**

```
<Controller
    defaultValue = {''}
    ...
/>
```

**2) Check context value** 
Check initial context value and update them like this.

```
data: {} => data: { field1: '', field2: ''}
```

Comment: You just saved me from a mental breakdown! Thank you so much. Setting the defaultValue on Controller solved this issue (I was seeing it in my Jest tests).

Comment: Setting default value is no practical solution. What if I have tens of fields? Why should I set everyone's default value. And if I have an edit (not create) form I will need to test against the existing form values like so -> defaultValue={incomingData[fieldName] || ''}. There is no point in that. Hook forms should provide null default value for every field that the user does not provide default value

Comment: They don't explicitly mention it, but [this does seem to be "officially implied" way to go about things here](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#ControlledmixedwithUncontrolledComponents) (note the specified default value)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the form schema. You can define the  `defaultValue` on the hook `useForm` to fix this issue

```
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitted },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });
```

Comment: thanks its working. btw my issue fixed by using only defaultValues without schema