# React: Warning, a component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, controlled-component

I'm using [Google maps address autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) in my React app. It works by hooking into an input element, watching for changes, and providing a dropdown location select.

Relevant code:

```html
<InputGroup hasValidation className="mb-3">
    <FormControl id="autocomplete"/>
</InputGroup>
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
        
    // only specify the fields we need, to minimize billing
    const options = {"fields": ["address_components"]}

    const autocompleteElement = document.getElementById("autocomplete")

    if(autocompleteElement) {

        autocomplete.current = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(autocompleteElement, options);
            
        const listener = autocomplete.current.addListener("place_changed", placeSelected);
        return function cleanUp() {
            google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(listener);
        }
    } else {
        // nothing to do yet
        return;
    }
});
```

**However, I'm getting a warning in the browser console**:

`Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component`

Seems obvious enough- the autocomplete functionality is changing the input itself as opposed to using react state to make a controlled component. However that's the way I want it. Is there a way I can silence this error? I've tried adding an empty `defaultValue` and an empty `onChange` function, but still got the error. Thanks in advance!

(There were a few questions with the same issue, but nothing about deliberately disabling the warning)

Comment: Have you tried adding `value=""` yet?

Comment: Sooo, any news? Just curious, cause I'd like to close the tab ;)

Comment: @ChrisG Heh, sorry to keep your tabs open. value="" makes it so that I can't type in the field. I also tried going all the way and setting up state and value and onChange attributes, and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled error in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro)

Answer (score 13):

I have faced such warnings on a couple of projects here is one of the causes and solution.

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
```

```html
<input value={value} onChange={inputHandler} />
```

From the code above notice that the state initial value is "", check yours. Its possible you are using null or empty value.

You need to change it to empty string and that warning will disappear.

Let me know if its helpful.

Comment: This worked for me as a start point. I have a nullable string being returned from a service and the typescript model did not have a corresponding nullable property. Changed the return to an empty string and bam, warning gone.

Answer (score 6):

We cleared this error by simply adding default values to our form inputs:

```
<p style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Devices: </p>{' '}
<Select
    isMulti
    value={mapValuesToSelect(devices) || []}
    //       this one rigth here      ^^^^^ 
    onChange={(e) => editDevicesMultiSelect(e)}
```

or simple input:

```
<Input
    type="text"
    value={code || ''}
    //          ^^^^^
```

P.S. we also have a handleSelectOnClose function:

```
<Button onClick={handleUnselect}>
    CLOSE
</Button>
const handleUnselect = () => {
    dispatch(setCurrentDesk(undefined));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular uncontrolled html `input` instead of one of the controlled react-bootstrap inputs.
You can use a `ref` to refer to the input.

```
<InputGroup hasValidation className="mb-3">
   <input
          defaultValue="Belgium"
          type="text"
          ref={this.autocomplete} />
</InputGroup>
```

More info on uncontrolled inputs and `ref` usage here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: I tried this after you suggested it, but I'm still getting the same error. I tried with and without a ref. I also tried using a normal <input> with a value and onChange, but that doesn't seem to word either.

Comment: Can you share your updated code that uses the `input` directly ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a third party custom package like:
[React Places autocomplete](https://tintef.github.io/react-google-places-autocomplete/).
This package provides an option to use controlled input, as well as other props to customise styling and other methods

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  selectProps={{
    value,
    onChange: setValue,
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an initial value and an `onChange` method. I'd probably use a hook to make this easier to manage. You could then use the `useEffect()` hook to call the API when the value of `inputText` changes.

```js
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    if (inputText.length > 0) {
        ... call the api
    }
},[inputText])
```

```js
<InputGroup hasValidation className="mb-3">
    <FormControl id="autocomplete" value={inputText} onChange={(event) => {setInputText(event.target.value}}/>
</InputGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

as *Blessing Ladejobi* said its beacuse of

`<input value={myValue} onChange={inputHandler} />` and `myValue=null`

solution is define a default value for `myValue` (like myValue="")