# How to properly edit a value of a put/patch request on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an edit caption of a post feature on my app. I am fetching a get request and then save that data in a state that will display on screen. The problem here is that it take a few second to load that data on screen. After editing the caption, which I have a onChange function that will update the state with the new edited caption. The new edited caption is followed by a put request that will update the caption of the post.
The problem here is that I am getting an error saying to change it to either a controlled or uncontrolled state. What is the right way of doing it?

Edit: For some reason, the error isn't showing on the console now with the same code I had previously without changes. So I guess that problem is fixed? But like I mentioned before, the caption would show up empty and then show the value of the caption 2 seconds after. Is there a way to show it instantly? Im assuming it not possible since It need to make a get request first and then store the data in the state, right?

The error I'm getting

`Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.`

Below is my code

```
const PostDetail = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({ caption: "" });
    const { id } = useParams();

    // once data is fetched, update the edited caption to the post
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchDetails = async () => {
            const res = await api.get(`/post/${id}`)
                .catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
            const data = await res.data;
            return data;
        }
        fetchDetails()
            .then((data) => {
                setInputs({
                    caption: data.post.caption
                });
            });
    }, [id]);


    const sendRequest = async () => {
        const res = await api.put(`/post/update/${id}`, {
            caption: inputs.caption
        })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        const data = await res.data;
        return data;
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(inputs);
        sendRequest()
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .then(() => navigate('/myposts'))
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInputs({ caption: e.target.value })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {inputs &&
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" boxShadow=" 10px 10px 20px #ccc" maxWidth={500} margin="auto" padding={3} marginTop={10} borderRadius={5}>
                        <Typography fontWeight={"bold"} padding={3} textAlign={"center"} fontSize={22} fontFamily="georgia">Edit Your Post</Typography>
                        <InputLabel sx={{ mb: 1, mt: 2, fontSize: 15 }}>Caption</InputLabel>
                        <TextField value={inputs.caption} name="caption" onChange={handleChange} fullWidth />
                        <Button variant="contained" type="submit" color="warning" sx={{ marginTop: 3 }}>Submit</Button>
                    </Box>
                </form>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: could you please attach more detail about the error that you are getting?

Comment: @MirzaUmair Just did

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro

Comment: Also you are combining together two sets of syntaxes for async calls. Use either `async/await` with `try/catch/` or `then/catch` clauses.

Comment: @Terminat the .then is not inside the async function. It is wrapped inside useEffect with the async function.

Comment: @Jason not really, you have `await` and `catch` in the call of `api.get()` call in `fetchDetails`

Comment: @Terminat ah.. didnt catch that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs when an input's value switches from null or undefined to a real value or vice-versa.

My guess is that `data.post.caption` isn't present in the fetch response, so you end up setting the input's value to `undefined`.

This makes it an *uncontrolled* input.

Then you type in the field, state gets updated, and you set the input's value to a string, making it a *controlled* input.

Hence the warning.

If that's the case you could mitigate it by ORing it with an empty string: `data.post.caption || ""`.

Comment: data is not a global variable

Comment: I edited my post. Apparently the error is not showing now without any code changes.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting data was a global variable. I was suggesting you OR it when setting state.

Comment: Is it possible the error isn't showing now because you've saved a caption on this particular post, so it now has a value on the initial load, whereas previously it didn't?

Comment: Im saying data is not a global variable so it will never have a value and will always be the other value using OR. and It always had an empty caption value saved. I didnt make any code change.

Comment: What does being global have to do with you doing `setInputs({ caption: data.post.caption || ""})`? Good luck.

Comment: My mistake... I thought you were referring to inside of useState. Thats why I said data is not a global variable thus it will be undefined so it wouldnt make sense to use OR with it.