# Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. Minimum working example

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-component, controlled-component

When **selecting an item**, the following **warning is raised**:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

**Minimum Working Example**

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";


export default function Inputs() {
  //const [gender, setGender] = useState("");

  return (
    <TextField select
                //onChange={e => setGender(e.target?.value)}
            >
        <MenuItem key={"a"} value={"a"}>a</MenuItem>
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

See the problem: [Gif](https://i.gyazo.com/4442324d9f20eed7a2b63d3a5fe40e7f.mp4)

Try it out yourself: [Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-3495-w2tl18?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Very cool that you included an example on the codesanbox.  I have to ask why do you have `MenuItem` inside `TextField`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Because that's how they have it in the official docs too https://i.gyazo.com/f5f002d9a594c909da403170e8ed683d.png

Comment: Makes sense. As in the answer. You are missing a state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled error in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding value to `TextField` error disappears:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function Inputs() {
  //const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  return (
    <TextField
      select
      value={data}
      onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}
    >
      <MenuItem key={"a"} value={"a"}>
        a
      </MenuItem>
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

Seems like `TextField` started in uncontrolled mode.

Comment: This can  be improved to safeguard for `data` that is undefined `value={data || ''}`

Comment: @nordic70 `data` is initially `''` and of it's `undefined` for some reason an error should be thrown, it helps finding the issue

Answer (score 1):

In your sandbox, prior to selecting the option you already receive the following warning:

```
MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are `a`. 

    in SelectInput (created by MuiOutlinedInputInput)
    in MuiOutlinedInputInput (created by InputBase)
    in InputBase (created by OutlinedInput)
    in OutlinedInput (created by Select)
    in Select (created by TextField)
    in TextField (created by Inputs)
    in Inputs
```

Though MUI's `Select` can be used in either a controlled or uncontrolled mode (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), you need to specify the initial value in some fashion. If you want to use the uncontrolled mode, then you should specify `defaultValue=""`. If you want to use the controlled mode, then you would specify `value={gender}` (along with uncommenting the code for managing the state). Specifying the initial value in one of these two ways avoids the warning that you mentioned in your question.