# Component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm building a site useing graphql and apollo with a react front end.  I have created a page where the site admin can update the content for particular sections of pages and it works, but I keep getting the error in the console: Component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled...

I'm also using ReactQuill wysiwyg editor.  I thought that might be the problem but I remved it and I'm still getting the same error.

Here is the code for the content update page:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GET_CONTENT_BY_ID } from '../../utils/queries';
import { UPDATE_CONTENT } from '../../utils/mutations';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

const Content = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_CONTENT_BY_ID, {
    variables: { id: id },
  });

  const [contentHead, setContentHead] = useState('');
  const [contentText, setContentText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const content = data?.contentById || {};
    if (content) {
      setContentHead(content.contentHead);
      setContentText(content.contentText);
    }
  }, [data, setContentHead, setContentText]);

  const [updateContent, { error }] = useMutation(UPDATE_CONTENT);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { data } = await updateContent({
        variables: {
          id,
          contentHead,
          contentText,
        },
      });
      navigate('/_admin');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="contentHead">
        <Form.Label>Section Heading</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          value={contentHead}
          onChange={(e) => setContentHead(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="contentText">
        <Form.Label>Text</Form.Label>
        <ReactQuill
          name="contentText"
          value={contentText}
          theme="snow"
          onChange={setContentText}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

In the ReqctQuill I tried onChange={(e) => contentText(e.target.value)} but there wasn't any change. The way it is now is what I got from, I think, their git repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in another question on here.  It wasn't the accepted answer but it works to get ride of the error.

[A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled error in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012169/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-of-type-text-to-be-controlled-erro)

So for my form I change value={contentHead} and value={contentText} to value={contentHead || ''} and value={contentText || ''} and that works and gets rid of the error!