# What is the real difference between value and defaultValue in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

on the homepage of React, there's the last [example](https://reactjs.org/#a-component-using-external-plugins) (**A Component Using External Plugins**) with a `textarea`:

```
    <textarea
      id="markdown-content"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      defaultValue={this.state.value}
    />
```

As I type, the `textarea` gets updated.

Now, I tried to change `defaultValue` with `value`:

```
    <textarea
      id="markdown-content"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      value={this.state.value}
    />
```

And the outcome is the same (as with `defaultValue`, i.e. as I type, the `textarea` gets updated visually with the updated text).

So, what is the real difference between the two?

Comment: Check this bro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146105/react-input-defaultvalue-doesnt-update-with-state

Comment: it's in the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Comment: Would definitely recommend reading the documentation.
But to answer the question, defaultValue is only used for initial rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you change the value that is used in `value` there won't be any difference. If you won't update the variable and have set a textareas value you can't change the value of the textarea by typing. By using a defaultValue you don't have to update any variable.

Comment: This means that `<textarea defaultValue={initialValue}/>` without an `onChange` handler will allow me to change the input value (**uncontrolled component**), while `<textarea value={initialValue}/>` will not (**controlled component**), right?

Comment: Right. To change the value with the `value={..}` property you need to assign a onChangeHandler.

Answer (score 5):

I think a good example for this is if you use a hard coded string

### using defaultValue prop:

```js
function App(){ 
  return(
    <textarea
      defaultValue="foo" // only by default foo
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

### using value prop

```js
function App(){ 
  return(
    <textarea
      value="foo" // will forever be foo
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

So while the snippet below this paragraph might look like it is the same as using `value` prop because of `onChange` potentially updating the state value (therefore it looks like it is updating `defaultValue` prop) - it is not. It is **still** an uncontrolled component and will update its value directly from the user input. It is simply initialized with the default value of whatever `this.state.value` is when it is initially rendered.

```
<textarea
  id="markdown-content"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  defaultValue={this.state.value}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

[see demo image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFto1.png)

> You can edit the input value without onchange event handler when you use **default value** with the input tag.
>
> If you use **value** with input tag you need to use onchange event handler to make changes to input value.

[image: Code sample]