# react input chnage default value using hooks

Tags: reactjs

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    if (props.profile && props.profile.profile) {
        setFirstName(props.profile.first_name)
    }
})


return (
    <div>
        <CustomTextField
                    className={classes.InputField}
                    variant="outlined"
                    name="firstname"
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth
                    placeholder=""
                    onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                    value={firstName}
                />
    </div>
)
```

Here i am using react hooks state

Here, I am trying to change the default value which coming from api. But, I am not able to change on onChange method .

Please take a look how can i handle this .

Or any other way to handle this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to  use `onChange` or `useEffect` for setting the default value, just set the `value` with the props given in your `CustomTextField` and `useState`:

```
import { Input } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";

export function CustomTextField(props) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState(props.firstName);
  return (
    <Input
      onChange={(e) => {
        setFirstName(e.target.value);
      }}
      variant="outlined"
      name="firstname"
      type="text"
      value={firstName}
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return <CustomTextField firstName="Kiran" />;
}
```

[image: Edit pedantic-goldberg-2r1sx]

Comment: Both value and defaultValue will be there in input ?

Comment: Are you using `material-ui`?

Comment: Ok, I will do it for you in 2 minutes. Let me share an example in codesandbox.

Comment: @KiranSyoutubechannel Updated. Please see the link.

Comment: @MajidMohammadi I think it is better to use ```value``` instead of ```defaultValue```

Comment: @AyushGupta OP want to set defaultValue of the input. If we set the value with `props.firstName`, input doesn't change when we change the value of the input.

Comment: @MajidMohammadi ```defaultValue``` is used in *uncontrolled components*.  Change ```defaultValue={firstName}``` to ```value={firstName}``` in your sandbox and notice that it does change. For more information, refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000466/what-is-the-real-difference-between-value-and-defaultvalue-in-react-js

Comment: @AyushGupta Thank you for your attention. I updated my answer. That's true.

Comment: @MajidMohammadi Glad to help