# React setState inside onChange function doesn't update input values

Tags: reactjs

```
function ProjectsComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ one: 1, two: 2 });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, two: state.one + 5 });
    console.log(state);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input defaultValue={state.one} onChange={handleChange} />
      <input defaultValue={state.two} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

When the first input changes, function `handleChange` is triggered, which changes the state of key `two` from 2 to 5+1 which is 6, but the second input default value `defaultValue = {state.two}` is still 2, how to update its value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React input defaultValue doesn't update with state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146105/react-input-defaultvalue-doesnt-update-with-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `defaultValue` prop is to set the initial value only. After the first render, the prop has no effect. By using the input in this way, you have an "uncontrolled" input. Typing into the input will update it, but you have no way other than that to set its value.

If you need to change the value externally, then you need to use a "controlled" component, which means you need to use `value` instead of `defaultValue`:

```
function ProjectsComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ one: 1, two: 2 });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, two: 1 + 5 });
  };

  const handleChangeTwo = (e) => {
    // I'm guessing this is what you want if input 2 is typed in
    setState({ ...state, two: e.target.value });
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <input value={state.one} onChange={handleChange} />
      <input value={state.two} onChange={handleChangeTwo} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

More info on controlled and uncontrolled components:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: but then if i did ```setState({ ...state, two: state.one + 5 });``` , the value of ```state.one``` will always be the value before change

Comment: i spent like a whole day trying to solve this issue ..

Comment: What would you like `state.one` to be? Are you looking for `setState({ one: e.target.value, two: 1 + 5 })`?

Comment: no, suppose i have many keys, e.g. one two three ..etc, when one changes, i want to set the state and use the updated value of one to set other keys

Answer (score 0):

write your console.log() out of the handleChange, you will see that it changes the state

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
setState({ ...state, two: 1 + 5 });
};

console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace prop `defaultValue` with `value` in both the Input components.

like this: `

```
<input value={state.one} onChange={handleChange} />
<input value={state.two} />
```

`

*Note: `defaultValue` prop is to set the initial value only, unlike `value` which sets the value of the component for each rerender.

Comment: but then if i did setState({ ...state, two: state.one + 5 }); , the value of state.one will always be the value before change, that's the real issue, i spent a whole day trying to solve this